# Bitwise operations on string representation of a binary number

Tags: qt, binary, bit-manipulation

What is the simplest solution to get a bit wise operation on a string representation of a binary number?

**Example**

```
QString a = "001";
QString b = "010";
QString c = "100";

// QString d = a | b | c -> d = "111"
```

Comment: Convert to integer, make operation and convert back to binary string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
QString a = "001";
QString b = "010";
QString c = "100";

QString d = QString::number(a.toInt(0, 2) | b.toInt(0, 2) | c.toInt(0, 2), 2);
```

It does what Alex Farber said. Converts the strings to integers, does the operation and then converts the result back to a string.